# « Pièce » ou « pièce de monnaie » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Dit-on :

> J'ai trouvé une pièce de monnaie sur le trottoir

ou

> J'ai trouvé une pièce sur le trottoir.

?

Je ne sais pas quelle expression est la plus utilisée.

Comment: Bienvenue sur *French Language*. Il est d'usage sur ce site corriger les erreurs (orthographiques et autres) lorsqu'on en trouve. Il n'est donc pas nécessaire de le demander explicitement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans ce genre de situation, il s'agit de savoir s'il y a une ambiguïté. Si on peut s'attendre à ce que la pièce soit autre chose qu'une pièce de monnaie ('pièce' est féminin), il faut préciser. Mais si le contexte ne crée pas de risque de confusion particulier, 'pièce' suffit.